# Swift : read .vcf file from document directory?

Tags: swift, iphone, cncontact, vcf-vcard

We get `.vcf` from Document directory path but can't import to the device using `.vcf` file URL like

> '"Nik1 .vcf":
>   file:///Users/jksol-niketan/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/18ADE140-22E4-4BEA-8C25-886AEE96C2CC/data/Containers/Data/Application/BC6A91A7-2920-4D5D-9787-F6D0E0DAB200/Documents/restore/Nik1%20.vcf'

How can solution for this file path URL to import iPhone device using swift/objective c
    I tired of this issue, help with this query solution.

```
for r in restore{
                  var data: Data = Data()
                            do{
                                let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: r.value.path)
                                try data = NSData(contentsOf: url) as Data
                                var usersContact = [CNContact]()
                                    do {
                                        try usersContact = CNContactVCardSerialization.contacts(with: data)
                                    } catch {
                                        print("error")
                                    }
                                let contact = usersContact[0]
                                print(contact)
                            }catch{
                                print("error")
                            }
                        }
```

> Ex. restore = ["Nik1 .vcf":
>   file:///Users/jksol-niketan/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/18ADE140-22E4-4BEA-8C25-886AEE96C2CC/data/Containers/Data/Application/BC6A91A7-2920-4D5D-9787-F6D0E0DAB200/Documents/restore/Nik1%20.vcf]

Comment: `print("error")` => `print("error: \(error)")` instead. Is there an error printed anyway? What is your issue exactly? What's wrong? Where is your code going? falling into a catch? Which one?